# How to get access for Push Notification, Contacts and Photos in a single alert in ios Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, user-permissions

I am building an app and in that am getting access for sending push notification, contacts and photos at three different time. But I don't want to trouble the user by asking it three different times.

How can I show a single alert and get access for all three with single tap?

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unfortunately this is not possible**, But the most close answer for your question is to present one elegant view that tells the user the benefits of giving permissions then after he clicks **OK** , show the alerts one after another. Then thank him for his favor :)

Take a look at [this](https://library.launchkit.io/the-right-way-to-ask-users-for-ios-permissions-96fa4eb54f2c#.5mu4zqwea) great article .